# Google Mirror API Subscription Proxy : HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: proxy, google-glass, google-mirror-api

1. I downloaded Google Glass Mirror API quickstart for .NET and it is working fine in the localhost.
2. Now, i want to subscribe for my app. Since localhost is not SSL enabled, i am trying to use  subscription proxy service provided by Google [here.](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/subscription-proxy)
3. When i append the proxy server URL, my call back URI looks like below.

   `https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=http://localhost:61422/oauth2callback`
4. Now, when i run the application, i get the error

   `Error: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL`

Anyone has encountered this issue?

Comment: Did you get this working? I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a publicly facing URL that Google can access for the callback. For this reason, you cannot use localhost because it is running internally on your machine and localhost does not resolve to your machines ip address.

I think that Microsoft is letting users sign up for one free month of Azure if you need a simple server to test the callback with.:https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/